# What method is called when incoming call is blocked by call directory extension

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

What method is called when incoming call is blocked by call directory extension. And is there any way to call a completion handler after a call has been blocked.

Comment: No method is called. The call is blocked. That's it.

Comment: And how can I get list of calls that were blocked?

Comment: You can't.  Any details of incoming calls would be a privacy violation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No method is called.  There is no way to know when the device has blocked an incoming call from a number provided by your CallKit extension.

Your extension provides a list of numbers that should be blocked.  These are transferred from your extension, out of your sandbox and into the device's phone app.  The phone app refers to this list when an incoming call is received and takes a block action if required.

Your extension is not involved in this process.

Any visibility of the numbers that were blocked would be a potential privacy violation.